# Rails - Setting default time in migration and testing with RSpec

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Working with Rails 4 legacy app & trying to set some DB defaults with Time. Using MySQL. I added a migration:

```
class AddDefaultsToCheckInAndCheckOut < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_default :rooms, :check_in_time, "12:00"
    change_column_default :rooms, :check_out_time, "09:00"
  end
end
```

---

The schema now shows:

```
t.time "check_in_time", default: "2000-01-01 12:00:00"
t.time "check_out_time", default: "2000-01-01 09:00:00"
```

The date part is no significance to me, although I am unsure why it is required when the column `type` is set as `time`

This may be caused by some setters defined in the `Room` model like so:

```
def check_in_hours=(hours)
  begin
    self.check_in_time = hours.present? ? Time.utc(2001,1,1, hours, self.check_in_time.try(:min)) : nil
  rescue ArgumentError
  end
end

def check_in_mins=(minutes)
  begin
    if self.check_in_time.try(:hour)
      self.check_in_time =  Time.utc(2001, 1, 1, self.check_in_time.try(:hour), (minutes.present? ? minutes : 0))
    else
      self.check_in_time =  nil
    end
  rescue ArgumentError
  end
end
```

---

I added some specs to check my work (room_spec.rb)

```
  it "defaults to 12:00 check in time if not specified" do
    expect(room.check_in_time).to eq "2000-01-01 12:00:00"
  end
```

---

Then also added to the factory (factories/rooms.rb)

```
check_in_time "2000-01-01 12:00:00"
check_out_time "2000-01-01 09:00:00"
```

The aim here was the mirror the schema default created by the migration I wrote.

---

However this spec fails:

```
  1) Room defaults to 12:00 check in time if not specified
     Failure/Error: expect(room.check_in_time).to eq "2000-01-01 12:00:00"
        expected: "2000-01-01 12:00:00"
        got: 2000-01-01 12:00:00.000000000 +0800
```

---

My question's relating to this are:

- How should be looking to implement this default?
- And how to test?
- Should I even be testing database defaults?
- Adding it to the Factory feels like it's just 'loading' the test.

Comment: Check you're always using either UTC or time-zone-specific timezone... if you're not sure, then convert both sides of the expectation.

Answer (score 2):

The time zone for "2000-01-01 12:00:00" is ambiguous, yet it's clearly defined for your date object. Not 100% sure by inspection, but comparing to "2000-01-01 12:00:00 +0800" may give you a passing test.

That said, this isn't a very useful test, especially at this degree of granularity, as it's trivial to the point where your test is more complicated than the actual code responsible for its behavior. However, if this value is super important and you want to keep the test, I'd recommend decreasing the time resolution of the comparison to only compare hours and minutes, or perhaps just hours, lest you have to maintain floating point errors, etc.

Comment: Thanks Anthony - I take from this that I should really just scrap the testing of this. It's overkill from a testing overhead perspective when I can see that the default is clearly defined in my schema. Thanks for the heads up on the TimeZone.